# MongoEngine EmbeddedDocument query with array value

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine, nosql

I have an object that looks something like this in the database, with corresponding MongoEngine models:

```
{
    ...
    "config" : {
        "inner_group" : {
            "individuals" : [
                {
                    "entity_id" : "54321",
                }
            ],
        },
        ...    
    }
    ...
}
```

I am trying to query this data using the `entity_id` field in the object which is part of the `individuals` collection.

I have tried querying according to the [MongoEngine docs](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html) but I have not been able to pull the data using the following:

```
data = Model.objects(config__inner_group__individuals__S__entity_id="54321")
```

How can I query the entire parent based on the `entity_id`?

Comment: `config__inner_group__individuals__entity_id="54321"`

Comment: Is it really that simple? So it doesn't matter that it's in an array then? I didn't even try it, because of section 2.5.2.3 on lists

Comment: It's really that simple. You just read the wrong part of documentation. This is basically ["Dot Notation"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) as covered in the core manual. The MongoEngine ( or django like ) way is to use `__` in place of `.`.